# How to initially load a Flatlist from the end of a data set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to use a flatlist to diplay all of the messages for a chat app, however I keep running into problems. The flatlist acts very strange, when there are more than 20-30 messages and the performance starts to get slower.

I've noticed that part of this problem is because when a messaging room is first loaded the flatlist will start at the beginning and then scroll all the way to the bottom of the message list, loading all the messages.

I've implemented my data component as `PureComponent` to try and increase performance, but it still seems to be behaving strangely. Is there a way that I can load in only the end of the flatlist initially and then when I scroll up load the rest of the messages?

Here is my code for the flatlist:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.messages}
  ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
  onContentSizeChange={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}
  onLayout={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated:true})}
  keyExtractor = {this._keyExtractor}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
/>

_renderItem = ({item}) => (
  <TextBubble 
    contents={item.contents}
    timestamp={item.timestamp}
    sender={item.sender}
    index={item.index}
    messages={this.state.messages}
    currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
    day={this.state.day}
    weekdays={this.state.weekdays}
  />
);

_keyExtractor = (item) => JSON.stringify(item.timestamp);
```

Here is where I get all the messages from Firebase in `componentDidMount()`:

```
let db = firebase.database();
let ref = db.ref("/rooms/" + roomNo + "/messages");
//the messages
let childData = [];
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  // firebase.database().ref('/users/'+username+"/rooms/"+roomNo+"/unread").set(false)
  childData = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    childData.push(childSnapshot.val())
  });
  this.setState({
    messages: childData
  })
}.bind(this));
```

I've tried reversing the array and then inverting the flatlist but that results in all kinds of weird behavior and still doesn't load from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the prop `inverted` to show flatListData inverted:

```
          ......
       <FlatList
            inverted
            data={this.state.messages}
            ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            ....
```

Comment: That doesn't completely work, if I only have a couple of messages they are rendered at the bottom of the screen instead of at the top plus I have to invert the array as well in order for the messages to be in the proper order.  There has to be a way to only load the end of the flatlist without having to invert it

Comment: try then in the FlatList props put style prop like this -->  style={{  transform: [{ scaleY: -1 }] }}

Comment: That renders everything upside down and inverts it

Comment: sounds like a feature to me

Comment: Apply scaleY: -1 to every message hahaha